# Why isn't the dropdown list relative to its parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why isn't my dropdown list positioning relative to its parent? There is a .Dropdown parent div which has position: relative set. The child "ul" element has position: absolute set. But when I try to set left: 0; or top: 0; to the ul element, it gets to the top left corner of the body instead of the .Dropdown element's top left corner.

Also the width: 100% of the .Dropdown-list (ul) element is not equal to the 100% of the actual parent.

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="Dropdown" id="Dropdown">
    <span class="Dropdown-toggle" role="button">Dropdown toggle</span>
    <ul class="Dropdown-list">
        <li class="Dropdown-item"><span class="Dropdown-caption">Choose one:</span></li>
        <li class="Dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" class="Dropdown-link Dropdown-link--active">Ipsum dsadas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="Dropdown-item">
            <a href="#" class="Dropdown-link">Dolor dasdas</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.Dropdown {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 10px;
}
.Dropdown-list {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 0; left: 0; THE RELATIVE PARENT IS NOT WORKING */ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    width: 100%;

    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px lightgrey;
    background: white;
}
.Dropdown-item {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de8hzuLq/)

Comment: For some reason, `.Dropdown {position: relative;}` isn't working.

Comment: Use a validator. http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input You seem to have some invalid, non-printing characters scattered about which are making the entire .Dropdown ruleset be ignored.

Comment: Thanks! You were right, there were some weird characters which invalidated the rules. The updated "working" version is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/de8hzuLq/2/)

Comment: @Quentin If you put that as an answer, I'd accept it.